# Why am I getting C++ Runtime Error in Google Kickstart Round C 2020 problem 4 (Candies)

Tags: c++

This is my first kickstart problem attempt (Round C 2020 problem 4 - Candies) and although my attempted solution works on vscode and passes the sample cases on the kickstart platform, it is giving me "runtime error" for test set 1. Any ideas why this is happening? I've tried changing the value of N (initially with a larger value it was giving me TLE) and "ints" to "long longs" but nothing seems to be working. I wrote my attempt based on the official analysis so I would have thought it would pass, although this is the first time I try using segment trees so maybe I'm missing something obvious with the implementation. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

const int N = 101; 
int n;
vector<ll> t(2*N);
vector<ll> t1(2*N);

void build() {
  for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) t[i] = t[2*i] + t[2*i+1];
}
void build2() {
  for (int i = n - 1; i > 0; --i) t1[i] = t1[2*i] + t1[2*i+1];
}

int sum(int a, int b) {
    a += n; b += n;
    int s = 0;
    while (a <= b) {
        if (a%2 == 1) s += t[a++]; //array[i++] is equivalent to array[i] THEN ++i; or i++; N.B. array[++i]; would be equivalent to ++i; or i++ THEN array[i];
        if (b%2 == 0) s += t[b--];
        a /= 2; b /= 2;
    }
    return s;
}
int sum2(int a, int b) {
    a += n; b += n;
    int s = 0;
    while (a <= b) {
        if (a%2 == 1) s += t1[a++]; //array[i++] is equivalent to array[i] THEN ++i; or i++; N.B. array[++i]; would be equivalent to ++i; or i++ THEN array[i];
        if (b%2 == 0) s += t1[b--];
        a /= 2; b /= 2;
    }
    return s;
}

void replace(int k, int x) {
    k += n;
    t[k] = x;
    for (k /= 2; k >= 1; k /= 2) {
        t[k] = t[2*k]+t[2*k+1];
    }
}
void replace2(int k, int x) {
    k += n;
    t1[k] = x;
    for (k /= 2; k >= 1; k /= 2) {
        t1[k] = t1[2*k]+t1[2*k+1];
    }
}

int main() {
    ios::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    ll T, q;
    cin >> T;
    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++){
        cin >> n >> q;
        for(int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            int temp, temp2;
            cin >> temp;
            temp2 = temp;
            temp = pow((-1),(i))*temp;
            temp2 = pow((-1),(i))*temp2*(i+1);
            t[i+n] = temp;
            t1[i+n] = temp2;
        }
        build();
        build2();
        ll ans = 0;
        char c;
        ll l,r;
        for(int i = 0; i<q; i++){
            cin >> c >> l >> r;
            l--;
            r--;
            if(c=='Q'){
                if(l%2==1){
                    ans-=sum2(l,r)-((l)*sum(l,r));
                }
                else{
                    ans+=sum2(l,r)-((l)*sum(l,r));
                }
            }
            else{
                if(l%2==1){
                    replace(l,-(r+1));
                    replace2(l,-((r+1)*(l+1)));
                }
                else{
                    replace(l,(r+1));
                    replace2(l,((r+1)*(l+1)));
                }
            }
        }
        cout << "Case #" << i+1 << ": " << ans << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show the full error message. Also trim down your code. Also **use meaningful variable names**.

Comment: @tadman As far as I can tell there is no error message on the google kickstart platform. It literally just says "RE". If I hover on top of this, it says "Runtime Error".

Comment: Take smaller steps. Do one thing - test, do the next, test.

Comment: If you're stumped, next step is to drop this into a debugger and find out *where* it crashes.

Comment: @tadman It isn't crashing on vscode though and it's passing the sample test cases

Comment: Sounds like undefined behaviour. Bugs don't have to behave consistently. Given how you do zero bounds checking in here it's not surprising that there's undefined behaviour. Some `assert()` checks might be in order.

Comment: Use the debugger - or if you're not used to it - litter your code with debug print outs. I confess - that's still my first "goto" debugging solution.

Comment: @TedLyngmo It's passing with all the test cases that I have available though. It works fine in vscode. Or is there some other way to use the debugger/print debugging to try and pinpoint why it's causing a runtime error on the kickstart judge?

Comment: @IanSamirYepManzano Passing tests is good. Passing human scrutiny is something completely different.